# Checking user answers in quiz app

Tags: algorithm, nlp

I am currently working on a quiz app and some of the questions have "long answers" where the user will need to type. I wonder if there is a standard way of checking whether these are right, given the obvious problem that everyone will phrase the answers in different ways. Any helpful tips or pointers are highly appreciated. (I would prefer non-ML answers)

Comment: Very non-trivial, more or less impossible to achieve. Unless you give the user a set of words to chose from or answer alternatives there is not much you can do. as soon as he has to type the answer completely by himself you will not be able to match it accurately.

Comment: Natural language understanding is an unsolved problem. Don't even try.

Comment: You're not doomed. Depends on your questions. Can you give examples?